# Number of common roots of $x^3 + 2 x^2 +2x +1 = 0$ and $x^{200} + x^{130} + 1 = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, contest-math

The equations $x^3 + 2 x^2 +2x +1 = 0$ and $x^{200} + x^{130} + 1 = 0 $ have

1. exactly one common root;
2. no common root;
3. exactly three common roots;
4. exactly two common roots.

I factored the first equation. I think the roots are $-1$, $\omega$ and $\omega^2$.

Comment: Can the roots be complex numbers? Also, what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes and yes. I factored the first equation. I think the roots are -1, \omega and \omega^2.

Comment: That is correct, but you should have put it in the question. I edited it for you in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$x^3+2x^2+2x+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)$$

The roots are $-1,\omega,$ and $\omega^2$, where $\omega,\omega^2$ are non real cube roots of unity.

Substituting in the other equation,
$$(-1)^{200}+(-1)^{130}+1=1\ne0$$
$$\omega^{200}+\omega^{130}+1=\omega^2+\omega+1=0$$
$$(\omega^2)^{200}+(\omega^2)^{130}+1=\omega+\omega^2+1=0$$

Thus, two roots are common.

Answer (score 3):

$\gcd (x^3 + 2 x^2 +2x +1 ,  x^{200} + x^{130} + 1 ) = x^2+x+1$, so two roots.

Note that you don't need to know the two roots, just that the gcd has degree $2$ and is coprime with its derivative (so no repeated roots).